# How to checkout Tomcat by SVN?

Tags: subversion, repository, url, tomcat

I try:

```
 svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/
```

But received error:

```
svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 
'http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk'
```

Is it mean that my svn doesn't work correct?

Comment: It suggests it doesn't know how to do HTTP requests. Is this a self-compiled `svn` binary?

Comment: yes. Should I add some options in configure?

Comment: Either that, or you're missing some dependency. Check the `./configure` script and the `README` or `INSTALL` files, and have a look at this [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/subversion_users/2Nhc-1ccAVQ). Good luck!

Comment: I have installed neon-config, but problem persists

Comment: check svn --version, it should list the ra_neon module.

Comment: thanks. It doesn't show ra_neon module. So need investigate why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the sequence(tested),

```
 svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/
 cd trunk
 svn cleanup './trunk'
 svn update './trunk'
```

Its working for me fine.